# CHUNKSIZE in openMP static scheduling

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, scheduling

Assume that each loop iteration of my code takes the same time.
 Please note that each loop iteration involves memory access from disjoint portions of a large contiguous memory. 
I am using VS2019 compiler.

I thought it should not matter whether I use

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static, CHUNKSIZE)
```

OR

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static)
```

I have used values like 5 for CHUNKSIZE.
I am asking this because I see the first variation performs slightly better.
Can someone throw some light?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not specify a chunk

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static)
```

OpenMP will:

> Divide the loop into equal-sized chunks or as equal as possible in the
> case where the number of loop iterations is not evenly divisible by
> the number of threads multiplied by the chunk size. **By default, chunk
> size is loop_count/number_of_threads**

Hence, for a `CHUNKSIZE=5`, `2 threads` and a loop (to be parallelized) with `22` iterations. To `thread ID=0` will be assign the iterations `{0 to 10}` and to `thread ID=1` `{11 to 21}`. Each thread with `11` iterations. However, for:

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static, CHUNKSIZE)
```

to `thread ID=0` will be assign the iterations `{0 to 4}`, `{10 to 14}` and `{20 to 21}`, whereas `thread ID=1` will work with the iterations `{5 to 9}` and `{15 to 19}`. Therefore, to the first and second threads it was assigned `12` and `10` iterations, respectively.

All this to show that having

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static)
```

and

```
 #pragma omp for schedule(static, CHUNKSIZE)
```

is not the same. Different chunk sizes, might affects directly the `loading balancing`, and cache misses, among others. Even if one:

> Assume that each loop iteration of my code takes the same time

Naturally, thinks get more complicated, if each iteration of the loop being parallelized is performing a different among of work. For instance:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
  for(int j = i+1; j < 22 ; i++)
     // do the same work.
```

With

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static)
```

`Thread ID=0` would execute `176` iterations whereas `Thread ID=1` `55`. With a load unbalance of 176 - 55 = `121`.

whereas with

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static, CHUNKSIZE)
```

`Thread ID=0` would execute `141` iterations and `Thread ID=1` `90`. With a load unbalance of 141 - 90 = `51`.

As you can see in this case without the chunk, one thread performed `121` parallel tasks more than the other thread, whereas with a `chunk=5`, the difference was reduced to `51`.

To conclude, it depends on your code, the hardware where that code is being executed, how you are performing the benchmark, how big is the time difference, and so. The bottom line is: you need to analyze it, look for potential loading balancing problems, measure cache misses, and so on. Profiling is always the answer.